# Import data from dynamics CRM using REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working on CRM Application to manage clients leads and tracking data's which is written in `ruby on rails`.

Now clients are asking me to pull existing leads from `Microsoft Dynamics CRM` which is already saved in their account.

But some of my clients not ready to share their login details with me.

So, I was planing to import data using API's. From last week and reading dynamics CRM documentation,but am not getting clear idea.

I tried below link

[OAuth 2.0 with Dynamics CRM Online](http://sharpshooting.github.io/authentication/2015/03/24/oauth2-on-dynamics-crm-online.html) but am not able to create app in `Microsoft Azure AD`.

I wants solution like `facebook` authentication way.

Please share some documentation or suggest me some ideas.

**Am Using**: Rails 4, apache, Linux, dynamics CRM 2011 and 2013

Answer (score 1):

> some of my clients not ready to share their login details with me.

I don't understand how you expect to connect without login credentials.

> Am Using: Rails 4, apache, Linux, dynamics CRM 2011 and 2013

I don't see how you can be on version 2011 and 2013 at the same time.

> Please share some documentation or suggest me some ideas.

Have a look at MSDN - [Authenticate users with Microsoft Dynamics CRM web services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328497(v=crm.6).aspx), make sure you select the correct documentation version at the top of the page. You could try claims based authentication.

Comment: 1. some of my clients not ready to share their login details with me. => I was planing to do import manually.

2. Am Using: Rails 4, apache, Linux, dynamics CRM 2011 and 2013 => I wants to import data with both version.

My intention is to communicate dynamics CRM using API's usin Azure Active Directory authentication.

Ex.how we are communicating to `facebook` and taking user information from there.